# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-municode’ in cygwin windows on running command make

Tags: cygwin, openvpn

I want some customization in openvpn-gui.

I use this build instruction from [Open VPN on github](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui/blob/master/BUILD.rst)

So when I run the command 'make' to build I got the error like below :

```sh
$ make

make  all-am

make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/users/VARIABLE/Documents/jay/openvpn'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -D_UNICODE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA -DWINVER=_WIN32_WINNT -municode -g -O2 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
```

This is the error:

> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-municode’

I have checked cygwin architecture either for 32 or 64 bit bu following command:

```sh
$ gcc -dumpmachine
```

The result of that command is:

> x86_64-pc-cygwin

How do I resolve that problem with the `-municode` command line option?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-municode` from the makefile? What result?

Comment: No. Actually, It was the error of the cygwin terminal. It was not completely installed on my computer, that's why this error I got. Not it is fixed. Thanks.