# g++: error unrecognized command-line option -municode using Cygwin

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, cygwin

I am trying to build [GetDP](https://getdp.info/) (finite-element sofware) from source using the 64-bit GNU compilers in Cygwin, namely gcc.exe, g++.exe and gfortran.exe, with their toolchain x86_64-pc-cygwin. I have the same error while linking the executable getdp.exe (in my case raised by the g++ compiler):

```
g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-municode’
```

How can I solve the issue? Are there some packages that can be installed within Cygwin to enable the -municode command in the toolchain of the compilers?
I have very little experience with C/C++ programming and compilation.
Any help is really appreciated.

Strictly related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524776/gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-municode-in-cygwin-windows-on-ru/73827913#73827913).

Comment: `-municode` is available for mingw-x64 targets. It makes no sense for cygwin. You probably need to install the mingw toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in Cygwin compiler toolchains, but in the CMakeList.txt file of the software I was trying to compile (GetDP).
Now the issue is fixed and the executable can be built without any errors using both gcc and mingw-x64 within Cygwin.